# Non-neural-network version of SoftmaxLayer[]

Tags: functions

Is there an built-in normalized exponential function (a.k.a. Softmax), equivalent to SoftmaxLayer[] but usable outside neural networks?

For example, the function would go from {1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3} to {0.024, 0.064, 0.175, 0.475, 0.024, 0.064, 0.175}. The total of the latter list is 1.

Comment: Could you give us a sample input you would like transformed?

Comment: @MarcoB any vector of numerical entries; say, {1,-2,3,4,7,5,1}

Comment: `list={1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3}; With[{exp = Exp[N@list]}, exp/Total[exp]]`?

Comment: @MarcoB Yes, thanks!  was wondering if there was a built-in function for that, though.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, are you looking for `Normaliza`? Also iirc you should be able to use the layer directly, but I'm on my phone at the moment so I can't check.

Comment: @CarlLange No, `Normalize` is the vector normalization, i.e., `v/Norm[v]` for a vector v. The entries of the normalized vector won't (necessarily) sum up to one.

Comment: @Anakhand Ah yes, my apologies!

Comment: `Normalize[Exp@{1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3}, Norm[#, 1] &]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in `SoftmaxLayer` can be used directly:

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3};
SoftmaxLayer[][list]

(* Out: {0.0236405, 0.0642617, 0.174681, 0.474833, 0.0236405, 0.0642617, 0.174681} *)
```

Note that `SoftmaxLayer` appears to automatically work at machine precision, probably because of its intended use in neural networks.

You could, of course, also calculate the result explicitly from the definition:

```
With[{exp = Exp[N@list]}, exp/Total[exp]]
```